# Sorting a list of objects based on another

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

```
public class Product
{
    public string Code { get; private set; }

    public Product(string code)
    {
        Code = code;
    }
}

List<Product> sourceProductsOrder = 
              new List<Product>() { new Product("BBB"), new Product("QQQ"), 
                                    new Product("FFF"), new Product("HHH"),
                                    new Product("PPP"), new Product("ZZZ")};

List<Product> products = 
              new List<Product>() { new Product("ZZZ"), new Product("BBB"),
                                    new Product("HHH")};
```

I have two product lists and I want to reorder the second one with the same order as the first. 
How can I reorder the products list so that the result would be : "BBB", "HHH", "ZZZ"?

**EDIT:**  Changed Code property to public as @juharr mentioned

Comment: So the two lists have a _separate_ `Product("BBB")` object, or is it the same object shared between the two lists?

Comment: Are they guaranteed to be in the other list?

Comment: It's a new one as you can see ;) Only with the same description...

Comment: @YoupTube I can see what the example code shows. I'm asking what's actually happening in OP's program.

Comment: @JLRishe It's a new object but with the same description.

Comment: @HélderGonçalves If they are different objects you either need to make `Code` public, or override the `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) method of `Product` to compare the `Code` value.

Comment: FYI: `Code` is currently a public field, not a property, which is generally considered a bad practice.  You can make it an auto property like this `public string Code { get; private set; }`.  This also makes the object immutable which you may or may not find desirable.

Comment: @juharr you're right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `IndexOf`:

```
var sourceCodes = sourceProductsOrder.Select(s => s.Code).ToList();
products = products.OrderBy(p => sourceCodes.IndexOf(p.Code));
```

The only catch to this is if the second list has something not in the first list those will go to the beginning of the second list.

MSDN post on `IndexOf` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `sourceProductsOrder.Select(s => s.Code).ToList().IndexOf(p)` will always yield 0 (asuming there is only one product of each description), or am I mistaken?

Comment: Thanks for that. Forgot to say `p.Code`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
products.OrderBy(p => sourceProductsOrder.IndexOf(p))
```

if it is the same `Product` object. Otherwise, you could try something like:

```
products.OrderBy(p => GetIndex(sourceProductsOrder, p))
```

and write a small `GetIndex` helper method. Or create a `Index()` extension method for `List<>`, which would yield

```
products.OrderBy(p => sourceProductsOrder.Index(p))
```

The `GetIndex` method is rather simple so I omit it here.

(I have no PC to run the code so please excuse small errors)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient way to do this:

```
var lookup = sourceProductsOrder.Select((p, i) => new { p.Code, i })
                                .ToDictionary(x => x.Code, x => x.i);

products = products.OrderBy(p => lookup[p.Code]).ToList();
```

This should have a running time complexity of O(N log N), whereas an approach using `IndexOf()` would be O(N<sup>2</sup>).

This assumes the following:

- there are no duplicate product codes in `sourceProductsOrder`
- `sourceProductsOrder` contains all of the product codes in products
- you make the `Code` field/property non-private

If needed, you can create a safeguard against the first bullet by replacing the first statement with this:

```
var lookup = sourceProductsOrder.GroupBy(p => p.Code)
                                .Select((g, i) => new { g.Key, i })
                                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.i);
```

You can account for the second bullet by replacing the second statement with this:

```
products = products.OrderBy(p => 
            lookup.ContainsKey(p.Code) ?  lookup[p.Code] : Int32.MaxValue).ToList();
```

And you can use both if you need to. These will slow down the algorithm a bit, but it should continue to have an O(N log N) running time even with these alterations.

Comment: Wouldn't there be an exception if the item from products wasn't in sourceProductsOwner here?

Comment: @IronMan84 Indeed there would be. I was in the midst of adding something to account for that.

Comment: @YoupTube It's not a copy. We arrived at similar solutions independently. And now my answer contains information that his doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a compare function that does a lookup of the order from `sourceProductsOrder` using a hash table. The lookup table would look like

```
(key) : (value)
"BBB" : 1
"QQQ" : 2
"FFF" : 3
"HHH" : 4
"PPP" : 5
"ZZZ" : 6
```

Your compare could then lookup the order of the two elements and do a simple `<` (pseudo code):

```
int compareFunction(Product a, Product b){ 
    return lookupTable[a] < lookupTable[b]
}
```

Building the hash table would be linear and doing the sort would generally be `nlogn`

Answer (score 0):

Easy come easy go:

```
IEnumerable<Product> result = 

products.OrderBy(p => sourceProductsOrder.IndexOf(sourceProductsOrder.FirstOrDefault(p2 => p2.Code == p.Code)));
```

This will provide the desired result. Objects with ProductCodes not available in the source list will be placed at the beginning of the resultset. This will perform just fine for a couple of hundred of items I suppose.

If you have to deal with thousands of objects than an answer like @Jon's will likely perform better. There you first create a kind of lookup value / score for each item and then use that for sorting / ordering.

The approach I described is O(n2).